# Azure Data Studio / VS Code - can't connect to dockerized SQL Server localhost

Tags: sql-server, docker, visual-studio-code

I've started a SQL Server Docker container on my Windows 10 host:

```
PS C:\> docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                                                  COMMAND                  CREATED         STATUS         PORTS                                                  NAMES
1b227ea458b5   mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-CU9-ubuntu-18.04   "/opt/mssql/bin/perm…"   7 minutes ago   Up 7 minutes   0.0.0.0:1433->1433/tcp                                 modest_leakey
```

I can open a cli to the container and do this:

```
mssql@99be3c0ebc18:/$ /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S localhost -U sa -P "secretpassword"
1> select name from sys.Databases;
2> Go
name                                                                                                                    
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
master                                                                                                                  
tempdb                                                                                                                  
model                                                                                                                   
msdb                                                                                                                    
test                                                                                                                    

(5 rows affected)
1>
```

But from Azure Data Studio, I cannot connect. I read some other posts and people have played around with the port like this:

```
localhost:1433
localhost,1433
localhost
0.0.0.0:1433
127.0.0.0:1433
```

I've tried them all - nothing works.

I've also tried to change the username "sa" to uppercase but that doesn't make a difference.

I'm getting an error

> Login failed for user 'SA'

I also am getting errors in VSCode while trying to create a connection.

I have blown away the docker container and volume a few times now in case.

Answer (score 0):

Have you searched in the SQL Server error log what is the issue? "Login failed" means you're able to reach the instance but the user is invalid for some reason, and that is found in the error log.

Comment: yeah.  i do a "tail -f /var/opt/mssql/log/errorlog" from inside the container ... and as I'm watching that I try to connect from VSCode or Azure Data Studio but nothing gets logged.  And i'm pretty sure i got the correct log only because I see other entries in it - same ones I see when I view the logs from docker desktop

Comment: Can you try with SQL Server Management Studio? It shows better descriptions about the issue.

Comment: I've tried a few combos but getting the same error.  What value should i specify for server name when trying to connect with SQL Server Management STudio?

Comment: You can use localhost, 127.0.0.1, . (just a single dot), your host IP, etc.

Comment: yeah i tried all those.  same error message

Comment: Have you checked if the firewall is blocking access to this port? It shouldn't by default, but you can search if the port is open in your host or try leaving it dynamic on the container to any that is free.